# How do I move the launcher?

Tags: 14.04, lts

I'm using 14.04 and would like to move the launcher to the bottom of the screen.

Is there a way to do this ?

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in Unity DE, there is no way to move the launcher or top bar. If you truly want something like that I would recommend using another DE such as xfce, kde, lxde, or mate. I hope you enjoy linux otherwise, though!